# ItemAdding or Item Added refresh Site

Tags: development

I looking for solution to refresh Site after Item Adding, or Ittem Added. I read this article, but I don't know how to use in my Code. 
http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/06/redirection-from-event-handler.html

Here is my code:

```
       public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdding(properties);

       if (properties.List.Title == "Wpisy")
       {
           SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Szczegoly"];

           // Stworzenie dwóch zmiennych typu data, jednej opisującej dzień Startowy, drugiej opisującej dzień końcowy
           DateTime dzienStart = new DateTime();
           DateTime dzienStop = new DateTime();

           // Podstawienie odpowiednich pól z propetisów pod wcześniej stworzone zmienne
           dzienStart = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["DzienStart"]).ToUniversalTime();
           // Zaistniała też potrzeba odjęcia dwóch godzin
         // dzienStart = dzienStart.AddHours(-1.0);
           dzienStop = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["DzienStop"]).ToUniversalTime();
         // dzienStop = dzienStop.AddHours(-1.0);

           // Uruchomienie pętli while, która to pętla będzie się wykonywać przez czas kiedy to zmienna dzienStart będzie mniejsza bądz równa zmiennej dzienStop
           while(dzienStart<=dzienStop){

               // Sprawdzenie Ifem, czy wybrane dni są równe sobocie, lub niedzieli
               if (dzienStart.DayOfWeek.ToString() ==  "Saturday" || dzienStart.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
               {
                   // Jeżeli zmienna ciągle inkrementowana dzienStart jest równa sobocie, lub niedzieli, to wwtedy następuje powiększenie dnia o jeden, zaś potem następuje kontynuacja pętli
                   dzienStart = dzienStart.AddDays(1.0);
                   continue;
               }
               // W przeciwnym wypadku następuje dodanie obiektu do listy
               else
               {              
                   SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add();
                   item["Kontrakt"] = properties.AfterProperties["Kontrakt1"];
                   item["Pracownik"] = properties.AfterProperties["Pracownik1"];
                   item["Dzien"] = dzienStart;
                   item["Procenty"] = properties.AfterProperties["Procenty"];
                  // item["ID z Czas Pracy Wpisy"] = properties.BeforeProperties["ID"];
                   dzienStart = dzienStart.AddDays(1.0);
                   item.Update();
               }
           }

          // SPUtility.Redirect("Event.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);

       } 

   }
   // Koniec ItemAdding
```

Comment: first of all why do you need to refresh the site after item adding or item added?

Comment: Because I want to have drop down List update. And It's only updating when a site is refreshing.

Comment: I still dont get your requirement, you want to update a drop down list without refreshing the site?

Comment: If it will be realizable it will be very good, If it isynt, i want to Reload site.

Comment: Simply bind the list of items when you click on drop down, fetch item by ajax call, that's it, it's pretty straight forward job

Comment: I don't cnow how. Have You got any simple code ?

Comment: I will try to create a sample code for you

Comment: So please Diptarg show me some sample code.